# How do you reset form properly in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I got this game. It works well. `form1` is the actual game and the `form2` is the scorescreen and there is a play again button. Whenever I play again it plays but after the games end and goes to `form2` which is the scorescreen it doesnt show any score at all and the game becomes unstable. Here is code:

```
Dim f2 As New Form2
            f2.Show()
            Me.Close()

Dim f1 As New Form1
            f1.Show()
            Me.Close()
```

Some images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really unclear question. If you only want to move to first page on PLAY AGAIN button, just show the first form;

```
 Private Sub PlayAgain_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayAgain.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()    
    End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I cant explain it very well Wow that was simple thanks a lot man!